# How do I retrieve Visio custom shape information with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-office, visio, office-2003

Using VBA, how do I retrieve custom shape information from a Visio 2003 diagram.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get custom shape information from a Visio shape:

```
Function GetCustomPropertyValue(TheShape As Visio.Shape, ThePropertyName As String) As String
    On Error Resume Next
    GetCustomPropertyValue = TheShape.CellsU("Prop." & ThePropertyName).ResultStr(visNone)
End Function
```

All this function does is uses the cellsu property on a shape to get the custom property ShapeSheet cell by name...

If you're a stickler about using the on error resume next, you can check to see if the cell exists by first checking if the cell exists:

```
if TheShape.CellExistsU( "Prop." & ThePropertyName , 0 ) then
GetCustomPropertyValue = TheShape.CellsU("Prop." & THePropertyName).ResultStr(VisNone)
```

Comment: `CellExistsU` returns an integer according to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/visio-vba/articles/shape-cellexistsu-property-visio). Are you sure it can be used as a boolean (0 for false, nonzero for true)?

Comment: yes I'm sure, the documentation doesn't really say what's returned but I've used it many times as a boolean.

Answer (score 3):

Found this, at http://visio.mvps.org/VBA.htm (Custom Properties)

```
Public Sub CustomProp()
    Dim shpObj As Visio.Shape, celObj As Visio.Cell
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, ShpNo As Integer
    Dim LabelName As String, PromptName As String, ValName As String, Tabchr As String

    Open "C:\CustomProp.txt" For Output Shared As #1

    Tabchr = Chr(9)

    For ShpNo = 1 To Visio.ActivePage.Shapes.Count
        Set shpObj = Visio.ActivePage.Shapes(ShpNo)
        nRows = shpObj.RowCount(Visio.visSectionProp)
        For i = 0 To nRows - 1
            Set celObj = shpObj.CellsSRC(Visio.visSectionProp, i, 0)
            ValName = celObj.ResultStr(Visio.visNone)
            Set celObj = shpObj.CellsSRC(Visio.visSectionProp, i, 1)
            PromptName = celObj.ResultStr(Visio.visNone)
            Set celObj = shpObj.CellsSRC(Visio.visSectionProp, i, 2)
            LabelName = celObj.ResultStr(Visio.visNone)

            Debug.Print shpObj.Name, LabelName, PromptName, ValName
            Print #1, shpObj.Name; Tabchr; LabelName; Tabchr; PromptName; Tabchr; ValName
        Next i
    Next ShpNo

    Close #1
End Sub
```